# Stored procedure. Check if constraint are used in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I get this error message:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_FieldMapper_Field". The conflict occurred in database "SCAM",
>   table "dbo.FieldMapper", column 'FieldID'.

I have some accesshelpers which has a given amount of fields. These Fields can be used by multiple accesshelpers..

When I delete an `accesshelper`, I need to check if the `fields` in the given `accesshelper` are used by other `accesshelpers`. If they are, I shall delete the accesshelper, but not the fields, as that would break other accesshelpers.
How do i do that?

This is what I have come up with on my own so far.

```
USE [SCAM]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[deleteAccessHelperById]

@Id int
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @projectIds TABLE (id int);
    INSERT INTO @projectIds ([id]) SELECT dbo.AccessHelperMapper.ProjectID FROM dbo.AccessHelperMapper WHERE dbo.AccessHelperMapper.AccessHelperID = @Id;

    DELETE dbo.AccessHelperMapper  WHERE dbo.AccessHelperMapper.AccessHelperID = @Id;

    DECLARE @fieldIds TABLE (id int);

    INSERT INTO @fieldIds ([id]) SELECT dbo.FieldMapper.FieldID FROM dbo.FieldMapper WHERE dbo.FieldMapper.AccessHelperID = @Id;


    DECLARE @AHfields TABLE (id int)
    Insert into @AHfields 
    Select fids.id from dbo.FieldMapper, @fieldIds as fids
    where dbo.FieldMapper.AccessHelperID != @Id
    and fids.id != dbo.FieldMapper.FieldID;

    delete dbo.FieldMapper where dbo.FieldMapper.AccessHelperID = @Id and dbo.FieldMapper.FieldID IN (SELECT d.id FROM @AHfields as d);
    delete dbo.Field where dbo.Field.ID in (SELECT g.id FROM  @AHfields as g);
    delete dbo.AccessHelper where dbo.AccessHelper.ID = @Id;


END
```

Comment: What is `@projectIds` here for?

Comment: I tried to make a table where i could store the IDs, but you are right, it should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code. Hope this is what you were looking for:

```
USE [SCAM]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[deleteAccessHelperById]

@Id int
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DELETE dbo.AccessHelperMapper  WHERE dbo.AccessHelperMapper.AccessHelperID = @Id;

DECLARE @fieldIds TABLE (id int);

INSERT INTO @fieldIds ([id]) SELECT dbo.FieldMapper.FieldID FROM dbo.FieldMapper WHERE dbo.FieldMapper.AccessHelperID = @Id
AND dbo.FieldMapper.FieldID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT dbo.FieldMapper.FieldID FROM dbo.FieldMapper WHERE dbo.FieldMapper.AccessHelperID != @Id);

delete dbo.FieldMapper where dbo.FieldMapper.AccessHelperID = @Id --and dbo.FieldMapper.FieldID IN (SELECT d.id FROM @fieldIds as d);
delete dbo.Field where dbo.Field.ID in (SELECT g.id FROM  @fieldIds as g);
delete dbo.AccessHelper where dbo.AccessHelper.ID = @Id;


END
```

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for the help. Well it did remove the error with the fieldmapper constraint, however it gave me a new error, this time with the accesshelperId.

'The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_FieldMapper_AccessHelper". The conflict occurred in database "SCAM", table "dbo.FieldMapper", column 'AccessHelperID'.

Comment: Yes that is because you still have few records for AccessHelperID = @Id in FieldMapper table. (Fields common to other AccessHelperID).

Comment: Yep, but what i'm trying to do is delete the accesshelpers, but check if the fields are used more than one place, if they are, i should delete my accesshelper, but leave the fields be. If they are not used, i'll delete the accesshelper and the fields.

Comment: Check the edited query. Field details will be available in Fields table. Deleting only from Mapper table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a transaction because you have partial data changes which cannot be applied separately.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[deleteAccessHelperById]
  @Id int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @fieldIds TABLE (id int);

    BEGIN TRY
      BEGIN TRAN

      DELETE ahm
      FROM dbo.AccessHelperMapper ahm 
      WHERE ahm.AccessHelperID = @Id;

      DELETE fm
        OUTPUT DELETED.fieldID
        INTO @fieldIds(id)
      FROM dbo.FieldMapper fm
      WHERE fm.AccessHelperID = @Id 

      DELETE f
      FROM dbo.Field f
      WHERE exists(select 1 from @fieldIDs fid where fid.ID = f.ID)
        and not exists(
          select 1 from dbo.FieldMapper fm
          where fm.fieldID = f.ID 
             and fm.AccessHelperID != @ID  -- redundant, may be removed.
        )

      DELETE ah
      FROM dbo.AccessHelper ah
      where ah.ID = @Id

      COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      IF XACT_STATE() IN (1, -1)
        ROLLBACK TRAN

      THROW;
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: I get the Error :

Incorrect syntax near 'THROW'. First i thought the throw were misplaced, but as far as i can see, everything is where it's supposed to be.

Comment: Which SQL SERVER version?

Comment: I use MSSQL 2017

Comment: `TRAN` got lost from `ROLLBACK`. fixed.